# Filtering string in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this method that will add tags to db.

```
def all_tags=(names)
  self.tags = names.split(",").map do |name|
    Tag.where(name: name.strip).first_or_create!
  end
end
```

It takes a string and strip it where there is a comma and add each string in db.
The problem is that a user can add duplicate tags ex 'red, blue, red'.

How can i check that user can't add tags that have the same name or remove the duplicate.

Comment: You need validations:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html.  Do you just want all tags to be unique or do you want each user to be able to have their own list of tags that is unique based on the user(Scoped validation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use uniqueness validator in your Tag model.

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :tag, uniqueness: true
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Comment: Thanks this is what I need.